# Codeigniter 3 validation error not showing along with callback function

Tags: codeigniter

I want to validate login form with ajax. I am using form valiation with a callback function that check username in database. When I am using callback with set_message, form validation errors are not working, only that callback error message is shown. If username is empty then form validation error like "Username is required" should be shown first and then if user enter wrong username then callback function error like "Username is not correct" should be shown

Following are the functions in my controller

```
public function validate_form()
    {
        $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_username_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|xss_clean|callback_password_check');
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $data['success'] = true;
            $this->session->set_userdata('admin_username', $this->input->post('username'));
        } else {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
                $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
            }
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
    }

    public function username_check()
    {
        $username = $this->input->post("username");
        if ($this->admin_model->usernameDB()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('username_check', 'The {field} is not correct');
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function password_check()
    {
        $password = $this->input->post("password");
        if ($this->admin_model->passwordDB($password)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            $this->form_validation->set_message('password_check', 'The {field} is not correct');
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Following are the function in my model

```
public function usernameDB() {
        $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $query = $this->db->get('adminuser');

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function passwordDB() {
        $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
        $query = $this->db->get('adminuser');

        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Following is the ajax that i am using

```
$("#admin_login_form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var me = $(this);
        // perform ajax
        $.ajax ({
            url: "validate_form",
            type: "post",
            data: me.serialize(),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response) {
                if (response.success == true) {
                    $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error')
                                    .removeClass('has-success');
                    $('.text-danger').remove();
                    window.location = "member";
                } else {
                    $.each(response.messages, function(key, value) {
                        var element = $('#' + key);
                        element.closest('div.form-group')
                        .removeClass('has-error')
                        .addClass(value.length > 0 ? 'has-error' : 'has-success')
                        .find('.text-danger')
                        .remove();
                        element.after(value);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I want proper validation errors order like if username or password is empty then first their relevant errors should be shown like username or password is required and then wrong or correct username or password errors should be shown.
[image]

Comment: `xss_clean` is not a valid rule for CodeIgniter versions >= 3.0.0

Comment: I do not understand what is not working.

Comment: have you tried what dfriend suggested? further it is best to use `trim` before `required` e.g. `trim|required|your_callback`. also i've never seen, in any auth system, a check for whether or not a password already exists in the database. i would suggest against it, and I would HIGHLY recommend not using `md5` and instead use `password_hash` and `password_verify`. MD5 is not secure as it can easily be broken even by phps own account: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

Comment: I have updated my question with screenshot, when both fields are empty, required error should be shown.

Comment: yes, i am using form validation with ajax, if i remove callback function then required is working but along with calllback, only callback message is printed, i want both form validation

Comment: You might want to reconsider giving detailed information about what is wrong with the login. Do you really want someone who is forcing their way in helpful clues? Perhaps a nonspecific "Improper Credentials" or "Incorrect Login" without details about what's right or wrong would be better in this situation. The "required" message is ok though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below. You can use single callback function to check whether user is exists or not.

First, remove the callback functions `public function username_check()` and `public function password_check()` from your controller and replace with the updated functions below.

In addition to this created new model function `login` inside `admin_model` which will check whether user is exists or not. Also you can delete both `usernameDB` and `passwordDB` from your `admin_model`.

Controller function:

```
public function validate_form()
{
    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|trim|xss_clean|is_user_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data['success'] = true;
        $this->session->set_userdata('admin_username', $this->input->post('username'));
    } else {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}

public function is_user_exists()
{
    if ($this->admin_model->login($this->input->post('username', TRUE), $this->input->post('password', TRUE))) {
        return true;
    } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_user_exists', 'Login failed. Username or password is incorrect');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Model function:

```
public function login($username, $password)
{
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', md5($password));
    $query = $this->db->get('adminuser');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note: Using `md5` for encrypt password is not good. See Alex's comment for more details.